# Monitor Java application with VisualVM

Tags: java, testing, amazon-ec2, profiling, visualvm

I have a few Java programs running on my EC2 instance. I want to profile them using VisualVM. they are not web applications that run on Jetty or Tomcat. I did go through the stuff mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543882/debugging-visualvm-remote-connection), but I dont know how to set up my VisualVM after I generate the jar files with those commands. Can some help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You normally attach VisualVM to the PID of the process you want to profile.  If that's Jetty or Tomcat or some other Java EE app server, that means the PID of the app server.  If not, it's the PID of the JVM that's running your app.

If you've already got a JVM installed on your EC2 instance, I'd recommend looking in the JVM /bin folder to see if jvisualvm.exe is already there.  If it is, fire it up in a separate command shell and attach it the PID of your application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. I have the JVM installed .. I need to run the visualvm on my local machine .. how do I make use of PID of the process to monitor it remotely?

Comment: I followed the steps in http://gabenell.blogspot.com/2010/04/connecting-to-jmx-on-tomcat-6-through.html.. But now I do not want to monitor the tomcat, but just an simple java application on the server (that I run using java app )... How can I do that?

Comment: Start Visual VM in one window, start the app, find the PID in the list displayed by Visual VM, and attach Visual VM to it.